# Global parametrization of submanifolds

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Is the following true ? :

Let $M$ be a $C^1$-submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension $k\leq n$ (without boundary). There is a $C^1$-map $f$ on an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^k$ such that $M=f(U)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This true, just take an atlas $(f_i,U_i)$ of $M$ where $f_i:U_i\subset R^k\rightarrow M$. Without restricting the generality, we can suppose that $U_i\cap U_j$ is empty if $i\neq j$. Then take $U$ to be the union of the $U_i$ you can define $f:U\rightarrow R^n$ whose restriction to $U_i$ is $f_i$.

Comment: If $f$ is assumed to be a $C^1$-diffeomorphism, then $S^{n-1}$ would seem to be a counterexample in the case where $M$ is assumed to be connected. Nice quick counterexample, though.